# ODM inheritance document with type SINGLE_COLLECTION schema create error

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have inheritance document with type `SINGLE_COLLECTION` configured in my Symfony 4.4 app.
When i run command `bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:create`, then error occurs `a collection 'db.Person' already exists`.

Everything was done according to the documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.0/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-collection-inheritance

**src/Document/Person.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorField("type")
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorMap({"person"=Person::class, "employee"=Employee::class})
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var integer|null
     *
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

**src/Document/Employee.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Employee extends Person
{

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $grade;
}
```

It looks like command is trying to create DB collection for every Document class, ignoring declaration of SINGLE_COLLECTION type.

How to fix it?

Comment: Collections in MongoDB do not need to be explicitly created. What is the failing operation exactly?

Comment: I'know that it is not needed, but I prefer to create full DB schema for indexes.

Extended error response is:
`MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: a collection 'db.Person' already exists in vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/CreateCollection.php:222`

Comment: What is the complete stack trace?

Comment: Oleg, I cannot get stacktrace. When I run `bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:create -vvv` I got a response:
`a collection 'db.Person' already exists`
`Created indexes for all classes`

Answer (score 2):

ODM's `odm:schema:create` is iterating through all metadatas and tries to create a collection without considering possible relations between them. A proper fix would be in the ODM's `SchemaManager` to either check whether a collection exists prior to creating or catching exception and ignoring it in case of existing collection.

I have created https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/2182 to track this issue. If you have some time to spare we will appreciate a PR!